# Is there a more efficient way to format this function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

I've come up with this function to find the probability of encountering a certain `type`, a column in a pandas data frame and I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this to structure that the parameter, instead of being an entire query, can just be the type name `def P(type = ""):`?:

```py
#Get count of each type
type_counts = data.groupby('type').count().drop('first_word', axis = 1) #get rid of unwanted data
type_counts = type_counts.reset_index()
#Rename 'name' column to appropriate name count
type_counts.rename(columns = {'name':'count'}, inplace = True)
#Types: company, drug, movie, person, place

prob_company = P(data.query('type =="company"'))
prob_drug = P(data.query('type =="drug"'))
prob_movie = P(data.query('type == "movie"'))
prob_person = P(data.query('type == "person"'))
prob_place = P(data.query('type == "place"'))

prob_company + prob_drug + prob_movie + prob_person + prob_place
```

Comment: `data[data['type'].isin(['company','drug','movie','person','place']]`? Or `data['type'].isin(['company','drug','movie','person','place'].mean()`?

Comment: looking more for a function and the mean definitely wouldn't do it because im finding the individual probabilities of each type